# compare current year and month of date in query using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the schema as following :

Test

```
const test = sequelize.define('test', {
        id: {primaryKey: true, type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, unique: true},
        start_date: {type: DataTypes.DATE},
           });


    return test
```

Now in different rows I have start_date as `2018-05-05,2018-05-06 and 2018-06-06.` Now what I want is ,I want to get the result `2018-05-05 and 2018-05-06`, which are for current month and year. How should I put the query for that in sequelize?

Comment: Are you saying you want to "query" between those days or "group" totals for each day? The "query" should be the same between various database backends, but "group by" will be different depending on the actual backend database. Which database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how to select dates, then as long as you are consistently working from a supplied JavaScript `Date` object and the `DATE` type for the column then simple range selection is just a matter of supplying the dates and using range operators such as `$gte` and `$lte`

```
const { Op } = Sequelize = require('sequelize');

let query = {
  where: {
    start_date: {
      [Op.gte]: new Date("2018-03-01"),
      [Op.lt]: new Date("2018-04-01")
    }
  }
};

let data = await DateTest.findAll(query);
```

Of course the preferred `Symbol` implementation requires a modern nodejs environment to support this in the notation of objects. If you don't have that, then you can still use "strings":

```
let query = {
  where: {
    start_date: {
      '$gte': new Date("2018-03-01"),
      '$lt': new Date("2018-04-01")
    }
  }
};
```

If you want to `GROUP BY` on a column with a `DATE` type, then the methods actually differ depending on the database engine on the backend, so that's best demonstrated with complete listings:

#### SQLite syntax

```
const { Op } = Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite:dates.db', { logging: log });

const DateTest = sequelize.define('DateTest', {
  start_date: Sequelize.DATE
});

(async function() {

  try {

    await sequelize.authenticate();
    await DateTest.sync({ force: true });

    let result  = await sequelize.transaction(transaction =>
      Promise.all(
        ['2018-03-01','2018-03-01T01:12:23.000Z','2018-04-01'].map(d =>
          DateTest.create({ start_date: new Date(d) },{ transaction })
        )
      )
    );

    let query = {
      attributes: [
        [
          sequelize.fn('strftime', '%Y-%m-%d', sequelize.col('start_date')),
          'date'
        ],
        [sequelize.fn('count','*'),'count']
      ],
      group: [sequelize.col('date')],
      where: {
        start_date: {
          [Op.gte]: new Date("2018-03-01"),
          [Op.lt]: new Date("2018-04-01")
        }
      }
    };



    console.log(query);
    let data = await DateTest.findAll(query);
    log(data);

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }

})()
```

#### PostgreSQL Syntax

```
const { Op } = Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const uri = 'postgres://user:password@localhost/database';

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
const sequelize = new Sequelize(uri, { logging: log });

const DateTest = sequelize.define('DateTest', {
  start_date: Sequelize.DATE
});

(async function() {

  try {

    await sequelize.authenticate();
    await DateTest.sync({ force: true });

    let result  = await sequelize.transaction(transaction =>
      Promise.all(
        ['2018-03-01', '2018-03-01T01:12:23.000Z','2018-04-01'].map(d =>
          DateTest.create({ start_date: new Date(d) },{ transaction })
        )
      )
    );

    let query = {
      attributes: [
        [
          sequelize.fn('date_trunc', 'day', sequelize.col('start_date')),
          'date'
        ],
        [sequelize.fn('count','*'),'count']
      ],
      group: [
        sequelize.col('date')
      ],
      where: {
        start_date: {
          [Op.gte]: new Date("2018-03-01"),
          [Op.lt]: new Date("2018-04-01")
        }
      }
    };



    console.log(query);
    let data = await DateTest.findAll(query);
    log(data);

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }

})()
```

Actually the `date_trunc()` should work with various SQL RDBMS back ends, but notably not with SQLite, just in case you even considered for testing purposes if not "lite" distribution.

Both forms would output:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2018-03-01",
    "count": 2
  }
]
```

Indicating that we only "selected" dates occurring in the month of March from the inserted sample with the query conditions, and that with the `GROUP BY` we truncated by "day" in order to achieve the expect total count of `2` for the given day.